# How to lock the spinner after button click in android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, spinner

**How can I prevent the user to change the value selected in `spinner` after some event like button press?**

*It is like after selecting the desired value from `spinner` the user will press a `button` after which they will not be allowed to see the values in the `spinner` except the top value i.e. the selected one so that no change be made in the selected value.*

**UPDATE:- And yes the `spinners` are also created dynamically on the press of that `same button` so it should lock only the previously created spinners not the new one.**

*Code for dynamic creation of `Layout` which contains the `Spinner` along with an `EditText` & a `Button`:-*

```
 View.OnClickListener addListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final RelativeLayout newView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_row_detail, null);

            newView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ImageButton btnRemove = (ImageButton) newView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
            btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    container.removeView(newView);
                }
            });

            container.addView(newView);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple just disable the spinner on button click

`spinner.setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 2):

In your onClick method, you can just set the visibility to GONE to remove the view as shown below:

```
View.OnClickListener addListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RelativeLayout newView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_row_detail, null);

        newView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ImageButton btnRemove = (ImageButton) newView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // remove (hide) your view
            }
        });

        container.addView(newView);
```

And to enable it again, you can set its visibility to VISIBLE as shown below:

```
newView.setVIsibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Or you could just show/hide your spinner as shown below:

```
your_spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // to remove (hide)
your_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  // to make it visible
```

If you want to only disable the spinner:

```
your_spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will remove the visibility of entire new layout, right?

Comment: Yes, it will remove the visibility of the entire layout including its child views

Comment: that layout contains `Spinner` along with `EditText` and `Button` but I don't want to disable anything else except the spinner.

Comment: You can simply hide your spinner or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable (may be `boolean flag = true`)

On button click change to `flag = false`

And inside Listener to Spinner **check if flag is true of false**

**Example**

//inside listener of spinner

```
if(flag){
//do task
}else{
//restrict the task or don't do anything or display message
}
```

**For Updated question**

Then you should use disable() method. spinner1.disable() or spinner2.disable() or so on..

Comment: :-) Keep the else block empty, simple

Comment: And in if block, do the task that you want

Comment: @Amit or use disable method as indicated by PrivatMamtora